# How can I match specific character between specific range in the string?

Tags: php, regex

I have this string:

```
$str = "here is start of rage, also here is some text and here is the end of string";
//              ^^^^^                                                 ^^^
//                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Now I'm trying to remove all `e` letter between this range: [`start` - `end`]. Well I want this **output**:

```
$newstr = "here is start of rag, also hr is som txt and hr is th end of string";
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Apply the regex just to the substring of the string and put the string together after it.

Comment: @Rizier123 Yes it will be fine, but isn't there any **pure-regex** solution?

Comment: @stack maybe, but why do you want to overengineer regex here? It's completely a problem where you do not need regex, and better don't use too

Comment: @RoyalBg To be honest, I'm trying to improve my knowledge about regex and increase my skills to  write complex patterns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `preg_replace` and the `\G` anchor:

```
echo preg_replace('~(?:\G(?!\A)|\bstart\b)[^e]*\K(?:\Be|e(?!nd\b))~S', '', $str);
```

details:

```
~
(?:
    \G(?!\A)   # contiguous to the previous match, not at the start of the string
  |            # OR
    \bstart\b  # the word "start"
)
[^e]*          # all that is not an "e"
\K             # exclude all previous matched characters from the whole match 
(?:
    \Be        # an "e" that is not the start of a word
  |            # OR
    e(?!nd\b)  # an "e" that is not followed by "nd"
)
~  
S  # the STUDY modifier that tries to improve non-anchored patterns
```

This pattern find one "e" at a time. Once the word "start" is found, the `\G` anchor forces the next match to be contiguous, since it matches the position at the end of the previous match. When the word "end" is reached `(?:\Be|e(?!nd\b))` fails and the contiguity is broken (until an other eventual word "start").

Note that this pattern doesn't check if the word "end" exists in the string (but it can easily be done). If the word "end" doesn't exist, all "e" will be removed from the word "start" until the end of the string.

Comment: @stack: **regex101 is not PHP**. `preg_replace` performs a global replacement, when regex101 without adding the g modifier stops at the first match. regex101 doesn't the support the S (uppercase) modifier.

Answer (score 2):

You could combine the [substring](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) and [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) functions.

Use substring to store the three parts of your string: 0 to start, start to end, end to the real end of your string. Then you can use trim on the middle portion, and then output the concatenation of those three parts.

Comment: `trim()` ?? Why exactly should I use that function? I think you mean use `str_replace()`

Comment: @stack `trim()` accepts a charlist to replace with nothing.

Answer (score 1):

[Substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) and [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) is your choice for this case

```
<?php

$str = "here is start of rage, also here is some text and here is the end of string";
//              ^^^^^                                                 ^^^
//                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
$start = 8;
$end = 65;

$newStr =
    substr($str, 0, $start).
    str_replace('e', '', substr($str, $start, $finish - $start)) .
    substr($str, $finish);

var_dump($newStr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you really want regex for this, but here is one solution

```
$str = "here is start of rage, also here is some text and here is the end of string";
preg_match_all("/(.*?)start(.*?)end(.*?)$/", $str, $matches);
$newstr = $matches[1][0] . "start" . str_replace("e", "", $matches[2][0]) . "end" . $matches[3][0];
var_dump($newstr);
```

It captures all before `start`, all between `start` and `end`, and everything after `end` too. In other words - 3 groups.

The part between `start` and `end` should be `e`-trimmed. The other parts should stay there, so we just restore them.

I believe same can be achieved using `preg_replace_callback`