# How to count the number of matched characters?

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to replace a sequence of numbers with zero. Always want to keep first digit and replace all the rest with zero. Something like this:

```
$numb    = 4124;
$newnumb = 4000;  // what I want
```

---

**Note:** Sometimes there is a float number like this `212.1`. For float numbers I don't match float part. So in `212.1`, I just match `212`.

---

Here is my pattern:

```
^(\d)([^\.]+)
```

Now `$1` contains first digit, and I want to know how can I put `0` instead of the rest of the digits?

---

Examples:

```
423.13 => 400
1232   => 1000
99.123 => 90
```

---

How can I do that using regex?

Comment: `$numb`, well that is a new one..... `;)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `\G` anchor:

```
echo preg_replace('/(?:\G(?!\A)|\d)\K\d(?:\.\d*)?/S', '0', $num);
```

details:

```
(?:
    \G        # position after the previous match 
    (?!\A)    # (but not at the start of the string)
  |           # OR
    \d        # first digit (you can also check if there is no leading dot)
)
\K            # start the match result at this position
              # (to preserve the first digit)
\d
(?:\.\d*)? # eventual decimals (you can change * to + to avoid to
           # remove a dot that ends a sentence)
```

More efficient way *(with `\d` in factor at the beginning)*:

```
echo preg_replace('/\d(?:(?<=\G.)|\K\d)(?:\.\d+)?/', '0', $num);
```

Comment: I think you are the best person that can use `\G` anchor. Because this is second answer that I get from you *([your first answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36049576/how-can-i-match-specific-character-between-specific-range-in-the-string#36050318))* .. thank you again

Answer (score 3):

As you already have the prefect regex `^(\d)([^\.]+)` you just need to use `preg_replace_callback()` and use the amount of characters in the second capturing group for the amount of 0's you want to print with `str_repeat()`, e.g.

```
echo preg_replace_callback("/^(\d)([^\.]+)\..*/", function($m){
    return $m[1] . str_repeat(0, strlen($m[2]));
}, $string);
```

Comment: @stack If you want to remove the float part, just add `\..*` to the end of the RegEx

Comment: @stack *float part is still there* I then read your question wrong. If you want to get it removed, as Druzion said just use `\..*` to match the dot and everything after it. (will update the answer)